# Review result page did not show the actual post

Tags: bug, low-quality-posts, review-queues

I did a review and, when I realized it didn't really "look okay", I wanted to take a second look at it. But this is the screen shown -- the question body is not shown below the review result. This seems unusual. I had to then manually go to the post to take appropriate action. Other review results are fine. Looks like this is just for this one.

Here are the [review result](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/343439), and [the actual post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/505785/50044).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now after checking through review results from many of my past reviews, it seems to me that this is by design for reviews of Questions - so no actual post is shown in the result page.

Only the reviews of Answers show the actual post under the result page.

Just posting this here for anyone who might come across a similar situation.